# Is there a difference between 摆 and 放?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I know that both are supposed to mean "to place" but are they interchangeable? I know that 摆 can be used in the following manner:

```
桌子上摆着三本书。
```

So could you also say something like

```
桌子上放着三本书。
```

and have it be a valid sentence?

Comment: cf.＂汉语动词３８０例＂  **摆／放**｜ **一、摆**  １。他的屋子里摆着两盆花儿。动词＂摆＂的意思是把物件放在一定的位置，也表示把物品陈列出来供人观赏。如～椅子、～家具、～商品等。２。开会的时候，大家摆事实，讲道理。＂摆＂在这儿意思是把事实、理由等罗列叙述出来。如～条件、～理由、～矛盾等。３。有的人爱摆阔气。＂摆＂在这儿的意思是故意在别人面前显示或夸耀自己。表示这种意思时，不单独做谓语，常含有贬义。如～架子、～威风、～排场等。４。见到主人，那条狗不停地摆着尾巴。＂摆＂在这儿的意思是物体向相反方向来回移动或变动。如～手、～小旗等。   **二、放** １。书架上放满了书。动词＂放＂的意思是把物件处于一定的位置。如～物品、～衣服、～自行车等。＂放＂和＂摆＂都有放置的意思，有时可以互换，它们之间的区别是：＂摆＂有排列出来供观赏的意思：＂放＂一般不含这种意思。２。明天放假，今天早点儿放大家回去吧。＂放＂在这儿意思是在一定的时间内停止工作或学习。如～学、～工、～暑假等。＂放＂还可以表示解除某种约束的意思，也表示使失去自由的重新获得自由的意思。如～人、～鸟、～俘虏等。＂摆＂不表示这些意思.

Comment: ３。他从没放过枪。＂放＂在这儿是把某种物体发出去的意思。如～箭、～鞭炮、～风筝等。＂放＂也表示将光或气体等散发开来。如～光、～气、～味儿等。＂摆＂不表示这种意思。４。这菜太淡，再放点儿盐。＂放＂在这儿的意思是把某种物品添加进去。如～水、～糖、～牛奶等。＂摆＂在普通话中不表示这种意思，但在有的方言中使用。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **擺放**
>
> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/15120/
>
> lay, layout, place, set

-

> **擺**
>
> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/2141/
>
> [1] [v] **lay**; put; **place**; **arrange**
>
> [2] [v] display; assume; put on
>
> [3] [v] state clearly; talk about
>
> [4] [v] wave; sway; swing; wag
>
> [5] [n] oscillating device; pendulum

-

> **放**
>
> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/862/
>
> [1] let go; release; set free
>
> [2] let out; dismiss; take leave
>
> [3] put; **place**; set; **lay**
>
> [4] let off; set off; send out
>
> [5] distribute; hand out; lend for interest
>
> [6] send into exile; exile; banish
>
> [7] (of flowers) blossom; come into bloom
>
> [8] enlarge; lengthen; **let out/down**
>
> [9] graze; pasture; put out to feed

The topic is the verb "to place". Both  擺 and 放 can be the verb for "to place", but 擺 also implies the object is placed in a particular position (arranged)

You can say 擺下陣勢 ( lay down a formation) but not 放下陣勢, because a formation has to be arranged.

```
桌子上摆着三本书。( more likely be neatly arranged)

桌子上放着三本书  ( either randomly or neatly positioned)
```

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid but with subtle differences. 摆 is more like "put for display", while 放 is just "put".